# Performing a different segue for each TableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, tableview

I have a populated TableView with several dynamic cells. I have the code to perform a segue once a cell is tapped, however I need to make it so that each cell performs a different segue. Can someone help me, because the code I am using just continues to perform the first segue no matter which cell i press!

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    NSLog("You selected cell number: \(indexPath.row)!")
    if indexPath.row == 0
    {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MoveToSignIn", sender: self)
    }
    if indexPath.row == 1
    {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MoveTo2", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have sections in table view?

Comment: I don't have sections no, just 6 Dynamic cells...

Answer (score 0):

What happens here (and I am pretty sure that's the problem) is the sections. It is impossible that one table have two cells with equal section and row values. Solution should be something like this :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    NSLog("You selected cell number: \(indexPath.row)!")
    if indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0
    {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MoveToSignIn", sender: self)
    }
    if indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 1
    {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MoveTo2", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Sections simply resets your rows, so it is easy to get confused since you have 5 rows but two sections or something pretty similar to that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried this and it still does exactly the same thing as before? I understand how I went wrong before and I thought this would work but still didn't :(

Comment: What does your NSLog say?

Comment: It does tell me which cell i selected, and it does change depending on which one i tap.
`2015-02-10 22:12:05.268 Alex[66789:2789442] You selected cell number: 2!`

Comment: Now that's really weird... I quickly created one project with 6 different cells and if conditions were working fine. Just in case, can you change NSLog("You selected cell number: \(indexPath.row)!") to NSLog("You selected cell number: \(indexPath.row) : \(indexPath.section"). The next thing would be clean-build (command + shift + K), and if none of that work, try adding condition for each row(doesn't matter if you haven't implemented anything, just log some string). It is impossible that you get 2 in the log and that is equal to 0 (If I got you correctly, you get first segue each time)

Comment: Tried this and still the same result! When i press on the first cell, it logs it as Cell 0 in the log, and then the second cell is Cell 1, etc. 
Could this possibly be caused by the fact that i am using storyboards and have linked the one dynamic cell to two ViewControllers, and added segues that way?

Comment: No -- I have one more suggestion for you: Can you double check that both of segues MoveToSignIn and MoveToView2 doesn't link to same view controller? Seems like last chance, if that fails, would you send me your project so I can try to fix it ?

Comment: Okay, I double checked and it they were both fine. However for some reason now it works... The only trouble is, is that when i click on the first cell, it goes to the first view controller, then the second! I don't want to show the first, i just want it to go straight to the second

Comment: add else if instead of if, that should help.

Comment: So just update it to this?
`if indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0
        {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MoveToSignIn", sender: self)
        }
        else if indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 1
        {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MoveTo2", sender: self)
        }`

Comment: Well, since I don't really know which code works for you now, just instead of second if put else if... Maybe that won't help as well since there could be some issues with segue... It is really hard to know what happened here since it suddenly started working :)

Comment: I think it might be to do with the segue and the way i implement them in storyboards! I create a segue between the cell and the firstviewcontroller, which is a selection segue, and the second segue between the cell and the secondviewcontroller is an accessory action. Could that be why? :)

Comment: Actually no, your segues shouldn't matter, you are calling one segue... Just Email me the project I will find what's going on and email you back with explanation.